# Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL

Tags: java, spring

я пытаюсь сделать авторизацию через Яндекс при помощи фреймворка Spring. Моё приложение должно получить доступ к следующим данным пользователя:

1.Доступ к логину, имени и фамилии, полу

2.Доступ к адресу электронной почты

3.Доступ к портрету пользователя

Эти данные я хочу получить в формате json.Вот мой код:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/goYandex",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String autorithationYandex(@RequestParam(value = "code", required = true) String code) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     //   User usr=new User();
      //  try {
            String str = mapper.readValue(new URL("https://login.yandex.ru/info?format=json&with_openid_identity=0&oauth_token="+code), String.class);
           // usr = mapper.readValue(new URL("https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=d099bc06048d4a0f87f98b8c9fc087a7"), User.class);
           // System.out.println(usr);
      //  }
        /*catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
return str;





//return code;


    }
```

Но при выполнении данного кода я получаю следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Comment: я так понимаю spring security подключён?

Comment: нет, его я пока не подключал

Comment: `String str = mapper.readValue(new URL("https://login.yandex.ru/info?format=json&with_openid_identity=0&oauth_token="+code), String.class);` вот это что такое?

Comment: Это запись в строку json полученного из URL:
https://login.yandex.ru/info?format=json&with_openid_identity=0&oauth_token="+code

Comment: не думаю, что объект класса `URL` вам нужно конвертировать в json строку. Скорее всего `ObjectMapper` кидает ошибку, когда пытаетесь это сделать.